# LocalSubmit and package functions

Tags: packages, scheduling

I want to use `LocalSubmit` to create continuous tasks that run in parallel. But it not works with functions from packages. For example:

```
BeginPackage["pack1`"]; 

func1[] := "function 1"

EndPackage[]; (*pack1`*)

BeginPackage["pack2`"]; 

Needs["pack1`"]

func2[] := LocalSubmit[func1[] >> "test.txt"]

EndPackage[]; (*pack2`*)
```

And if I run this code:

```
Needs["pack2`"]
func2[]
```

the following is written to the file *test.txt*:

> func1[]

I know how this problem can be resolved if packages in files *pack1.m* and *pack2.m*. `func2` must be defined as follows:

```
func2[] := LocalSubmit[Get["pack1`"]; func1[] >> "test.txt"]
```

There may be a better solution that saves the functions from the loaded contexts??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know how the 'separate kernel' is handled, whether it is killed after or will be reused but in case of the latter I'd expose needed package on `$Path` and add `` Needs["pack1`"] `` etc.

Alternatively you can embed needed definitions similarly to how they are embedded in `APIFunctions` and friends:

```
(*...*)

func2[] := LocalSubmit[
    Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[] = #; func1[] >> "test.txt"
] &@Language`ExtendedFullDefinition[func1]

(*...*)
```